# Prove $\lim_{ n \to \infty} m^*(A\cap(-n,n))=m^*(A)$ for any set $A$ (m is Lebesgue measure)

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim_{ n \to \infty} m^*(A\cap(-n,n))=m^*(A)$. This is clear for measurable functions, using continuity of measure, however how do we show it for any set? I am taking here about Lebesgue outer measure

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Denote by $I_n= (-n, n)$. The $I_n$ form an increasing sequence of measurable subsets with union $\mathbb{R}$. This is the only thing we need.

Since $I_n$ are measurable we have
$$m^{*}(A\cap I_{n}) = m^{*}(A\cap I_{n-1})+ m^{*}(A\cap (I_{n}\backslash I_{n-1}))$$
and therefore
$$m^{*}(A\cap I_{n}) = \sum_{k=1}^nm^{*}(A\cap (I_{k}\backslash I_{k-1}))$$

But we know that 
$$m^{*}(A) \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m^{*}(A\cap (I_{k}\backslash 
I_{k-1}))$$

It should be easy now.